# Weierstrass theorem and the series $\sum\frac{z^k}{k^2}$ and its derivative

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

The Weierstrass theorem states that if a series with analytic terms,

$f(z)=f_{1}(z)+f_{2}(z)+\cdots +f_{k}(z)+\cdots $

converges uniformly on every compact subset of a region $\Omega$, then the sum $f(z)$ is analytic in $\Omega$, and moreover $f'_{k}(z)$ converges uniformly to $f'(z)$ on every compact subset of $\Omega$. But why the series $\sum\frac{z^k}{k^2}$ fails this theorem on $|z|<1$, since its derivative $\sum\frac{z^{k-1}}{k}$ does not converge uniformly at all, because

Take a fixed $n$ and $z=(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{1}{2n}}$. Then

$|\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{z^{k-1}}{k}| >z^{2n-1}\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}>z^{2n}\sum_{k=n}^{2n}\frac{1}{k}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}$

This means for any $n$, we can find a $z=(\frac{1}{2})^{\frac{1}{2n}}$ to make the sum of terms between $f_{n}(z)$ and $f_{2n}(z)$ larger than a constant. But if the series converges uniformly, the sum should be smaller than a $\epsilon$ whatever $z$ is.

**Correction**

The proof does not work as I thought. The proof above shows that the derivative of the series does not converge uniformly on the $\Omega$. It does not show it does not converge uniformly on every compact subset of $\Omega$, since the $z$ I chose is escaping from every compact subset.

Comment: Why do you think that $\sum\frac{z^{k-1}}{k}$ does not converge uniformly on compact subsets of $|z| < 1$ ?

Comment: @MartinR Could you check my update. I give a brief proof why the series does not converge uniformly.

Comment: Your choice of $z$ approaches $1$, so eventually leaves any compact subset of the open disk.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh, thanks for this tip. I guess I misunderstood the theorem. The theorem states that the derivative of series converges uniformly on every compact subset of the region. It does not say the derivative will converge uniformly on the whole region. Am I right this time?

Comment: Your correction is correct. $z$ depends on $n$. The sequence $z_n=(1/2)^{1/2 n}$ converges to $1$ so any closed subset of the open unit disc $D$ centered at $0$ will contain $z_n$ for only finitely many $n$. However, you have shown  that the series does not converge uniformly on $D$

Comment: @user254665 Thanks for conforming this.